# FirebaseCrashlytics: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

So I followed the [Firebase Android guide for Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android), but this happens:

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:319)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:283)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:86)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:674)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:551)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:507)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:426)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:354)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:89)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:224)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:407)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
```

I tried both release and debug builds, both do not work. What do I need to do that the guide didn't mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. Solved by disabling any ad blocker

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a Crashlytics issue, but a cert issue. I suggest taking a look at this thread [android java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414958/android-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certific).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was being caused by [NextDNS.io](https://nextdns.io/) which was blocking Crashlytics requests.

You can whitelist the following domains:

- `*.firebase-settings.crashlytics.com`
- `*.crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com`